# Do you think it is a better option to put the site-menu in the header for user experience?

Tags: usability, user-expectation, visual-design, client, visibility

Hi i am trying to create a good experience for my clients. 
This is a demo of my site. My question is what is better regarding user experience when it comes to the site-menu?

Should i rather put the site-menu in the header or can is it okay to keep it below the hero-image regarding user experience?

I hope my question is right here, i am new to UX.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome,

visitors expect the menu on top in the header, most likely on the right since they usually expect a logo on the left.

If you don't have a logo you could use your name as a logo.

Your menu is not really visible right now, the transparent menu points aren't a good idea over a background-image.

Comment: Site menu should be on the right top because It is more conventional and user's reading pattern is "Z". That means when a user lands on a screen he'll read in horizontal manner.

Eye trackers revealed that people tend to read web content in an “F-Shaped” pattern. Keeping your navigation in a horizontal position up in the header plays well to this.